# Product::getProductsProperties(): 'id_image' returns 'en_default', not image

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I've build a module to make a custom page with some products. I've tried to

```
//get all products
$products_partial = Product::getProducts($this->context->language->id, 0, 1000, 'name', 'asc');
$products = Product::getProductsProperties($this->context->language->id, $products_partial);

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    //here comes some logic to select some products (not relevant for this question)

    //echo the image ID
    $results[] = $product;
}

$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'products' => $results
));

//this is a copy of themes/default/product-list.tpl
$this->setTemplate("product-list.tpl");
```

Now all products are shown, but without the right image. It turns out that $product['id_image'] is set to 'en_default', but I don't know why. But why?

I've tried to search for the problem on the PrestaShop forums, and I found people with the same problem ([1](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/211430-solved-problems-on-getting-id-image-help-needed/), [2](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/238211-category-listing-dont-show-image-of-new-products-inserted/)), but there was no solution given.

Comment: `var_dump($products)` before the for each and post the result

Comment: array (size=78)
  'id_product' => string '25' (length=2)
(..)
  'id_image' => string 'nl-default' (length=10)

Comment: I think that the 'PrestaShop' code is getting the last item of the array, so, something in it code must be wrong. You should see what the `setTemplate` method is doing in order to solve your problem.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with that array. It contains all products right (including text, title, price, etc.), but only the wrong id_image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a function, that sets the `en_default` and I think it is clear, why it does, what it does.

```
public static function defineProductImage($row, $id_lang)
{
    if (isset($row['id_image']))
        if ($row['id_image'])
            return $row['id_product'].'-'.$row['id_image'];

    return Language::getIsoById((int)$id_lang).'-default';
}
```

This is from 1.5 version.