# Prestashop : id_image is string "fr_default" and not the ID of the image

Tags: php, image, module, prestashop

In my prestashop module i have to display product with image. I have my variable products which contain all products data, but id_image not contain the real id of the image of the product but a string which is : "fr_default"

I found where this string is send with the following stackoverflow topic : [Product::getProductsProperties(): 'id_image' returns 'en_default', not image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820924/productgetproductsproperties-id-image-returns-en-default-not-image)

But there's no solution, I always have the '?' and the url image is not working.

I'm on Prestashop 1.6.0.6 and i write my products variable with those line :

```
$products_partial = Product::getProducts($context->language->id, 0, 40, 'name', 'asc');
$products = Product::getProductsProperties($context->language->id, $products_partial);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed a module in which I use this line to retrieve the images and links :

```
$products_partial = Product::getProducts($context->language->id, 0, 40, 'name', 'asc');
$products = Product::getProductsProperties($context->language->id, $products_partial);

foreach ($products as $key => $product) {          
    $cover = Product::getCover($product['id_product']);
    $products[$key]["id_image"] = $cover["id_image"];     

}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: @Victor Sigler I am not getting the images. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code, but I cannot display images.

Do you have an idea of the issues? thanks

```
public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();              
    $products_partial = Product::getProducts($this->context->language->id, 0, 0, 'name', 'asc');
    $products = Product::getProductsProperties($this->context->language->id, $products_partial);     

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'products' => $products,
        'homeSize' => Image::getSize('home_default')
    ));

    foreach ($products as $key => $product) {          
        $cover = Product::getCover($product['id_product']);
        $products[$key]["id_image"] = $cover["id_image"];     

    } 

    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'catalogue.tpl');

}
```